# Android custom font loading error

Tags: android, android-fonts

I try to use roboto black font in a textview, but `tx.setTypeface(tf);` is throwing an error. It says, "`Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`", and at `(tf)` "`Syntax error on token "tf", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token`".

Here is the snippit of code that I'm using to change the font:

```
TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moomoo);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Black.ttf");
tx.setTypeface(tf);
```

To my knowledge I only have to change the java file, while having the font ttf file in my assets folder, in a child of the assets folder called "fonts". I then just need a reference to the text view and can do everything from the constructor of the java class for the xml file's font that I'm trying to change, correct? Is my logic flawed, what am I doing wrong? Android is version 19.

Comment: is your tf not null?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Black.ttf");
```

to

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");
```

Comment: This helped a lot, also I didn't have it in the construct for my Android application, I had placed it just under the constructor and forgot to include it but moving the bracket. Thanks again for the help!